# QCustomPlot - scale every graph separately

Tags: c++, qt, qcustomplot

I am looking for solution how to have graphs in customPlot (Qt) that I will be able to scale every of them individually.

I have tried by adding individual axis for every graph, but it got very complicated.

Any suggestions?

As for now I have every graph with its own axis:

```
  QCPAxis *ax =  ui->customPlot->axisRect()->addAxis(QCPAxis::atLeft);
  //ax->setVisible(false);
  ax->setRange(INIT_Y_MIN, INIT_Y_MAX);
  scaleRatios.insert(scaleRatios.begin()+num,1.0);
  connect(ui->customPlot->yAxis, SIGNAL(rangeChanged(QCPRange)), ax, SLOT(setRange(QCPRange)));
  scaleAxes.insert(scaleAxes.begin()+num, ax);
```

but how influence on connect that rangeChanged will be scalled?

Comment: Did you look at multiple axis demo http://www.qcustomplot.com/index.php/tutorials/basicplotting? What didn't work for you? Could you please post your code?

Comment: I looked on that code for multiple axis, but there was no scalling.